kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable for a service in container try to create topic at "kafka:9092"
I have multiple services in Docker, including service A (consumer) and Lafka. Service A is the consumer. Below is the docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  service-a:
    container_name: service-a
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8881:8881"
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=development
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - chroma

  kafka:
    container_name: my-kafka
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@:9093
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes    

  chroma:
    container_name: learnsuite-chroma
    image: chromadb/chroma:latest  
    ports:
      - "8882:8000"

Note that the Kafka bootstrap_servers setting for my service-a (running in a docker container) is
bootstrap_servers: kafka:9092

And this setting will be used in the consumer creation in service-a:
def get_consumer_for_topic(topic: str):
    group_id = settings.kafka.group
    bootstrap = settings.kafka.bootstrap_servers
    bootstrap_servers = bootstrap.split(',') if bootstrap else []
    admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)

    try:
        topics = admin_client.list_topics()
        if topic not in topics:
            # Create the topic if it doesn't exist
            new_topic = NewTopic(name=topic, num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1)
            admin_client.create_topics([new_topic])
            logger.info(f"Topic '{topic}' created.")
        else:
            logger.info(f"Topic '{topic}' already exists.")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error ensuring topic exists: {e}")
    finally:
        admin_client.close() 
    
    return KafkaConsumer(
        topic,
        bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
        group_id = group_id,
        auto_offset_reset='earliest'
    )

If I run docker-compose up, I got error

kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable

I know many people talks about it, but this is where I got even after googled around. Please advise.
Answer: As the question had been marked deletion, it seems I cannot answer it, so update here for the people who might have similar issue.
The thing is the service-a has a really fast boot process. It hit the topic creation part before kafka fully booted. Therefore, I added a retry mechnism to basically let it wait. After that, from the log, I can tell it failed a the first time but then picked up at the 2nd time and eventually boot successfully.

Why did you think you needed to use host.docker.internal? https://docs.docker.com/compose/how-tos/networking/

@OneCricketeer, I tried localhost:9092 in my settings file, I got kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable error.

Presumably you're talking about the settings file of Service A, if so, it should reference kafka:9092 or kafka:9094, not localhost or any other hostname. See also Communicating between different docker services in docker-compose

@MarkRotteveel, yes. I tried that and I got the error when start service A. Please check my updated question.


Kafka Server doesn't start immediately. So, starting a Kafka client immediately will always fail to connect. Use a compose healthcheck to resolve this as depends_on will not wait for server uptime. 2) The correct address is set in your KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS line, as documented in the duplicate post, and it is not localhost, as that means your Python container itself, not Kafka... Btw, you don't need to list all topics before creating. The adminclient has an if-not-exists condition that can be applied


You are totally right, @OneCricketeer. Thanks for your suggestions.
